# If I share a dataset with another user in Power BI Service, what can he do with it?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to share a dataset with another user in Power BI Service. Obviously I want him to see the data the dataset provides. But I'm concerned about the possibility of a leakage.
Can the user who get's the shared dataset:

- see the connection string details?
- export the pbix?
- edit the dataset in some way?
- trigger an update?
- share it with others?
- delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the end user's privileges as set by the administrator of the **premium workspace** if this is what you are referring to.

For more information on this please see the attached roles that can be granted on a workspace level:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-new-workspaces#roles-in-the-new-workspaces

You can also share individual reports on a read-only level in Power Bi service (premium workspace).

If you do not have a **premium workspace** (you plan to share using your personal workspace):

The user of the report needs to have Power Bi pro license - Find more information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-purchasing-power-bi-pro